# Is it even possible to set default display settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, default

I'm using a second display. Everything works fine, until I have unstable electricity, resulting in the second monitor turning off and back on. 
With a problem - after said reboot, it sets itself at the highest possible resolution, with me forced to readjust it each time.
Is it even possible to set the default resolution to the desired one, so that after unexpected electricity reboots it just sets itself back to normal, as it should do?[image: resolutinons]

Comment: The default behavior is that these settings are remembered.

Comment: I've assumed the same, up until electricity problems started. Sometimes I get broken resolution, sometimes the display option is messed up also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using **x11 window system** you can use [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr) to achieve it.

Run `xrandr` to list all the connected outputs (probably `HDMI-1` if you're using HDMI for external monitor).

Then use something like,

```
xrandr --output <output> --mode <prefered_resolution>
```

This will last through your current session.

You can persist this using different ways. For ways in which xrandr can be configured see [configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Configuration)

Comment: You cannot if you use Wayland, the default for several Ubuntu versions now.

Comment: I will add it to my answer. As the user didn't mention anything I assumed he was using x11.

Comment: But you should assume Wayland if the current LTS or newer

Comment: Yeah. I actually use 20.04 on a daily basis so have never used wayland. So, it was more from habit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. For some reason integration with external monitors worked not as expected, to put it lightly. Both on slow old notebook and a brand new "gaming" one.

Comment: well, the closest thing to resolving I came up with was adding an alias for `xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 2560x1440 --primary --left-of eDP-1` . At least it works way better than the gui.